# LinkedIn App - Unable to Verify due to error in verification step

Tags: linkedin-api

I have been trying for a couple of days to verify an app on LinkedIn Developer portal, but getting an error each time I try. Is anyone else running into this? I've tried multiple apps and multiple computers.

[image]

Here are the steps:

1. Go to https://developer.linkedin.com/
2. Click on MyApps
3. Click Create App
4. Specify AppName, LinkedIn Page, Privacy Policy, Upload a Logo, Agree to terms. Click Create App
5. Request Access to Product: Sign In with Linked In
6. Go back to settings tab
7. Click Verify Button
8. Click Generate Url Button
9. Copy Url
10. Paste Url into browser window
11. Click Verify Button
12. Error pops up on bottom left of screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a few days later, and it worked. Must have been a prod issue on LinkedIn's servers